# Generator functions in node 0.12

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Are generator functions supported in Node?  I keep reading that they are since v 0.11.

Tried to run this snippet in node 0.12

```
function* range(max, step) {
  var count = 0;
  step = step || 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < max; i += step) {
      count++;
      yield i;
  }

  return count;
}
```

but no luck. Do I need to call npm start with a custom parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run node with `--harmony` flag to enable generators in node (0.11.x and 0.12.x versions):

```
$ node --harmony your_script.js
```

Comment: thanks, when I tried running it with --harmony I tried it through npm. didn't think of starting it with node